# Wordpress get_option not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms, function

I want to get array value from get_option following this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/how-to-save-wordpress-options-as-an-array) to add more but its not working for me. I can't find where I have gone wrong. It works when I am not using array.

**Working code (without array):**

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    register_setting('my-test', 'option1');
    register_setting('my-test', 'option2');
    register_setting('my-test', 'option3');
});

function my_function() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php
    settings_fields('my-test');
    do_settings_sections('my-test');
        ?>
         <input type="text" name="option1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option1') ); ?>"" />
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Then I want to use array to get_option. I followed the answer I mention above but it gives me error. Please see this code below.

**Not working code (with array):**

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    register_setting('my-test', 'option1');
    register_setting('my-test', 'option2');
    register_setting('my-test', 'option3');
});

function my_function() {
$new_option = esc_attr(get_option('option2'));
?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php
    settings_fields('my-test');
    do_settings_sections('my-test');
        ?>
         <input type="text" name="option1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option1') ); ?>"" />
         <input type="text" name="option2[first]" value="<?php echo $new_option['first']; ?>" />
         <input type="text" name="option2[second]" value="<?php echo $new_option['second']; ?>" />
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **esc_attr** function in the below line. This function takes string as input and returns string. Since you are dealing with array this will cause error.

```
$new_option = get_option('option2');
```

You should use the function where you are actually outputting the value.

```
<input type="text" name="option2[first]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_option['first'] ); ?>" />
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It's working now after I remove the esc_attr.